# Why am I unable to build the IOS app, I made

Tags: ios, flutter

I am trying to build an Flutter Ios App, and when I run "flutter build ios", I get an error like

```
error: No profiles for 'com.runin.carrick' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.runin.carrick'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner').
```

When I go to Xcode I go to Signing and Capabilities and there is 2 messages, It says I should plug in an IOS device, but I do not have one, is it required?

https://prnt.sc/uk7fi7

I already have a Paid Apple Developer Account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it without a mobile device, if you do to the Apple Developer website you can, create certificates but you have to use manual signing though.